# Constness and comparison concepts in generic code

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Taking a look at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/three_way_comparable)

```
template<class T, class U, class Cat = std::partial_ordering>
concept three_way_comparable_with =
  std::three_way_comparable<T, Cat> &&
  std::three_way_comparable<U, Cat> &&
  std::common_reference_with<
    const std::remove_reference_t<T>&,
    const std::remove_reference_t<U>&> &&
  std::three_way_comparable<
    std::common_reference_t<
      const std::remove_reference_t<T>&,
      const std::remove_reference_t<U>&>, Cat> &&
  __WeaklyEqualityComparableWith<T, U> &&
  __PartiallyOrderedWith<T, U> &&
  requires(const std::remove_reference_t<T>& t,
           const std::remove_reference_t<U>& u) {
    { t <=> u } -> __ComparesAs<Cat>;
    { u <=> t } -> __ComparesAs<Cat>;
  };
```

In all comparison concepts, the operands (`t` and `u` here) are always const-qualified references.

This means that if I have an "unorthodox" class

```
struct S {
    int i;
    auto operator<=>(const S&) const = default;
    void* operator<=>(S&) = delete;
};
```

then `S` models `std::three_way_comparable` but the following fails

```
S a, b;
a <=> b;
```

Does this mean that I must enforce constness for comparisons in [any generic code](https://godbolt.org/z/j9z7qchs4)?

```
template<typename T, typename U>
requires std::three_way_comparable_with<T, U>
auto foo(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    // if(t <=> u > 0)  // wrong!
    if(static_cast<const std::remove_reference_t<T>&>(t) <=>
       static_cast<const std::remove_reference_t<U>&>(u) > 0)
        return bar(std::forward<T>(t));
    else
        return baz(std::forward<U>(u));
}
```

Comment: Does S really model the concept? The implicit expression variations section may imply it doesn't.

Comment: The unorthodox class is explicitly disallowing comparison of non-const objects.  That is independent of and orthogonal to the generic code.  In other words, the generic code is fine, and the unorthodox class objects cannot be used in the generic code (as intended by the unorthodox class author), and the compiler detects that as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted by @StoryTeller in the comments:

According to the "*implicit expression variations*" in [[concepts.equality]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/concepts#equality-6), because the expression `t <=> u` is non-modifying (the operands are `const` lvalue references), variations of the expression expecting non-`const` lvalue references instead of `const` lvalue references are implicitly also required. However, it is unspecified whether these requirements are validated.

I don't see any exceptions to this rule for `std::three_way_comparable_with` in [[cmp.concept]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/cmp.concept).

Your type `S` violates this additional requirement because the variation

```
  requires(std::remove_reference_t<T>& t,
           std::remove_reference_t<U>& u) {
    { t <=> u } -> __ComparesAs<Cat>;
    { u <=> t } -> __ComparesAs<Cat>;
  };
```

is not satisfied. It therefore doesn't model `std::three_way_comparable_with`.

There is even a [very similar example](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/concepts#equality-8) under the referenced clause.

Comment: This is... deeply unfortunate. This makes behaviour _inconsistent across compilers_. Suppose I have a fallback `foo2` in case the type doesn't model `std::three_way_comparable`. It may or may not compile.

Comment: @PasserBy I guess it is not supposed to affect overload resolution since the concept is still satisfied, so it is the same as with other semantic requirements: Passing the type that satisfies only the explicit syntactic requirements to a function requiring the concept to be modeled is wrong, a fault of the caller and may or may not result in errors.

Comment: In that case, concepts aren't very suitable as means to turn off overloads. Which doesn't sound right.